# Textbox moves unexpectedly after text entry

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a text box in some html that has a jquery button attached to it.  If the user enters some text and then moves the focus away from the text box (using tab or the mouse) then the text box inexplicably moves down about 4 pixels.

```
<div class='input-append'>
    <input class="tin" type="text" name="s" />
    <button class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">GO!</button>
</div>
```

and the CSS:

```
.tin
{
    font: bold 1.9em sans-serif;
    height: 27px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
    -moz-border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
    border-radius: 12px 0 0 12px;
    width: 480px;
}
```

The unexpected movement occurs in Chrome & Safari, but not IE which seems to chop off some of the entered text (the outer border of the text box overwrites some of the bottom of the text which is reasonably large), which makes me think it is some kind of line-height issue perhaps?

Comment: You're going to need to add more code than that, the accompanying CSS and jquery at least. Is it possible for you to recreate the issue using your HTML and CSS for that section on jsfiddle?

Comment: Try to set same `line-height` in css for `input` and `input:focus`

Comment: look into using a `reset` css and properly calculate the height so that `27px` would be accurate for every browser.

Comment: Added a vertical-align:top to the .tin css which seems to have fixed it, normally I think it is aligned to the baseline.  It appears the height is changing by 1px for some reason - I thought the reason it was breaking might be font-size, but it still breaks when the .tin font is set to 1em.  Odd.

Comment: There's no jquery javascript code btw.

Comment: You don't need dynamic `line-height` inside the input with `height: 27px`... `font: bold 1.9em/27px sans-serif;`

Answer (score 1):

Just pure guess. It might have something to do with your css.

For instance:

```
.btn
{
    width: 90px;
}
.btn:focus
{
    width: 200px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code you sent. If I wrote like this

```
<style type="text/css">
        .tin
        {// the css}
    </style>
```

then the problem is replicated and if I wrote like this

```
<script type="text/css">
        .tin
        {//css}</script>
```

What approach you are using?